# Propagating plant cuttings

Tags: houseplants, cuttings

I have two Hoya cuttings (from different plants) and one of them started rooting. The other one hasn’t developed any roots yet.

I think I cut one of them to early but it was the only way to save the cutting.

So my question is, can I boost the rooting process by putting them in the same water or would this be counterproductive?

The one on the left has been in the water since 17 days an the one on the right since 20 days.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If none of them is rotting you could put them together but I do not think one would boost the other.

Sometimes you have to wait, and sometimes a cutting will not root no matter what. Keep them where they are, in a sunny spot and replace the water once a week.

Comment: So there is a real possibility that a cutting will not root? Thats good to know. Thanks for the help!

Comment: There’s always that possibility. OTOH, if after three weeks the cutting is still plump and fresh (as the one on the right seems to be, from the little I can see), I’d certainly not give up yet. Remember that they came from different plants, so different rooting times are quite possible.

Comment: FWIW I take cuttings from a large mahonia every year and root them in water. They usually take somewhere between 3 and 6 *months* but they all root eventually.

Comment: @MysteriousChallenger If you get impatient and throw the cutting away, it is 100% guaranteed not to root. Lots of plants are killed by impatience, IMO.

Comment: @alephzero How do you decide what to cut? I had to cut a fairly young shoot (the one on the right). Does that affect the rooting process in any way? Do you have any experience with that?